# How to remove first array element without changing original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array:

```
arr1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I need a way to remove the first element from `arr1` and save the returning array in a new variable like this:

```
arr1 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
arr2 = ['y', 'z'];
```

Comment: Set arr2 to equal arr1 to start by using slice (arr2 = arr1.slice(0);\). Then splice arr2 to remove unwanted element. arr1 will remain untouched and arr2 have new contents.

Comment: Question title says clearly "NOT returning new array", and the question equally clearly describes making a new array. Which is it?

Comment: IDK if you are using jQuery or not, but if so - you can just use clone() on the array and then update the clone while leaving the original in tact.

Comment: `slice` leaves the original array unchanged

Comment: the slice function/method may be what you're looking for arr2=arr1.slice(1) ... notice this does create a new array; arr2 does NOT share the storage with arr1. I do not think there's a way to do it in Javascript such that they share (it's JS, not C :)

Answer (score 4):

Make a copy of arr1 with `slice` and then use `splice` on that array.

```js
var arr1 = ['x','y','z'];
var arr2 = arr1.slice().splice(1, 2);

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
arr1 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
arr2 = arr1.slice(1, 3);

console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, we can use [`Array Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to ignore the first element, create another array from rest of the array elements and assign it to some other variable:

```js
let arr1 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
    
let [, ...arr2] = arr1;

console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`_.tail`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#tail) method from the Lodash library.

```js
var arr1 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var arr2 = _.tail(arr1);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```